Create Polygons, centered on points, and following the angled line before and after the point
Good morning - I need help with a python script ran in ArcGIS Pro 3.3 Notebook
I have a script that creates polygons centered on each point that aligns with the angle of the polyline as shown in FIG 1. The problem is FIG 2, where the polygons do not conform with the path of the polyline where angles occur.  What I must have, is what FIG 3 depicts of the polygon following the angles.
enter image description here
It currently works but is not producing the desired outcome.
# Name:        Create Polygons at Points
# Purpose:     Create a polygon centered at each Structure and 
               aligned with the angle of the polyline
# Created:     28/08/2024

import arcpy
import math

# Constants
WORKSPACE = r"PATH TO... Map.gdb"
STRUCTURES_LAYER_NAME = "Structures"
ALIGNMENT_LAYER_NAME = "Route"
OUTPUT_FC_NAME = "Aligned_Polygons"
TOLERANCE = 0.0125  # Updated tolerance

# Set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = WORKSPACE
def get_map_by_name(aprx, map_name):
    """Retrieve a map by its name."""
    maps = aprx.listMaps(map_name)
    if not maps:
        raise RuntimeError(f"No map named '{map_name}' found in the 
current project.")
    return maps[0]
def get_layer_by_name(map_obj, layer_name):
    """Retrieve a layer by its name."""
    layers = map_obj.listLayers(layer_name)
    if not layers:
        raise RuntimeError(f"No layer named '{layer_name}' found in the map.")
    return layers[0]
def set_layer_visible_scale(layer):
    """Set the layer to be visible at all scales."""
    layer.minScale = 0
    layer.maxScale = 0
    print(f"Set layer '{layer.name}' to be visible at all scales.")
def create_output_feature_class(output_fc, spatial_ref):
    """Create the output feature class."""
    if arcpy.Exists(output_fc):
        arcpy.management.Delete(output_fc)
        print(f"Deleted existing feature class '{output_fc}'.")
    arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(arcpy.env.workspace, output_fc, "POLYGON", spatial_reference=spatial_ref)
    print(f"Output feature class '{output_fc}' created successfully.")
def add_fields_if_not_exist(output_fc, fields):
    """Add fields to the output feature class if they do not exist."""
    existing_fields = {f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(output_fc)}
    for field_name, field_type in fields.items():
        if field_name not in existing_fields:
            arcpy.management.AddField(output_fc, field_name, field_type)
    print(f"Fields added to '{output_fc}'.")
def calculate_rotated_rectangle(center, width, height, angle):
    """Calculate a rotated rectangle's vertices."""
    angle_rad = math.radians(angle)
    dx = width / 2
    dy = height / 2
    corners = [(-dx, -dy), (dx, -dy), (dx, dy), (-dx, dy)]
    return [(center[0] + x * math.cos(angle_rad) - y * 
math.sin(angle_rad),
         center[1] + x * math.sin(angle_rad) + y * 
math.cos(angle_rad)) for x, y in corners]
def is_point_near_vertex(point, alignment_fc, tolerance=TOLERANCE):
    """Check if a point is near any vertex of the alignment features."""
    point_geom = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(*point))
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(alignment_fc, ["SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            geometry = row[0]
            if geometry:
                vertices = [arcpy.PointGeometry(pnt) for pnt in geometry.getPart(0)]
                if any(vertex.distanceTo(point_geom) <= tolerance for vertex in vertices):
                    return True
    return False

def main():
    # Prompt user for map name
    map_name = input("Enter the map name to use: ")
    # Prompt user for rectangle dimensions
    rectangle_length = float(input("Enter the rectangle length (in feet): "))
    rectangle_width = float(input("Enter the rectangle width (in feet): "))
    # Load the ArcGIS Project
    aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
    # Get the map and layers
    map_to_use = get_map_by_name(aprx, map_name)
    structures_layer = get_layer_by_name(map_to_use, STRUCTURES_LAYER_NAME)
    alignment_layer = get_layer_by_name(map_to_use, ALIGNMENT_LAYER_NAME)
    # Set layers to be visible at all scales
    set_layer_visible_scale(structures_layer)
    set_layer_visible_scale(alignment_layer)
    # Get feature class paths
    structures_fc = structures_layer.dataSource
    alignment_fc = alignment_layer.dataSource
    # Extract spatial reference
    spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(structures_fc).spatialReference
# Create output feature class
output_fc = OUTPUT_FC_NAME
create_output_feature_class(output_fc, spatial_ref)
# Define fields to add
    fields_to_add = {
        "Length_ft": "DOUBLE",
        "Width_ft": "DOUBLE",
        "Unique_ID": "TEXT",
        "Type": "TEXT",
        "Feature": "TEXT",
        "Height": "DOUBLE",
        "County": "TEXT"
    }
    add_fields_if_not_exist(output_fc, fields_to_add)
    # Collect points data
    points_data = []
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(structures_fc, ["OBJECTID", "SHAPE@XY", "Unique_ID", "Type", "Feature", "Height", "County"], sql_clause=(None, 'ORDER BY OBJECTID')) as structures_cursor:
        for structure in structures_cursor:
            current_point = structure[1]
            if is_point_near_vertex(current_point, alignment_fc):
                points_data.append(structure[1:])  # Collect all 
attributes except OBJECTID
    # Create polygons
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(output_fc, ["SHAPE@", "Length_ft", "Width_ft", "Unique_ID", "Type", "Feature", "Height", "County"]) as 
insert_cursor:
        for i, data in enumerate(points_data):
            current_point, unique_id, type_field, feature, height, 
county = data
            angle = 0  # Default angle for the first point
            # Calculate angle for the first point
            if i == 0 and len(points_data) > 1:
            second_point = points_data[1][0]  # Get the second 
point's coordinates
                dx = second_point[0] - current_point[0]
                dy = second_point[1] - current_point[1]
                angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(dy, dx))
            # Calculate angle for all other points
            elif i > 0:
                previous_point = points_data[i - 1][0]  # Get the 
previous point's coordinates
                dx = current_point[0] - previous_point[0]
                dy = current_point[1] - previous_point[1]
                angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(dy, dx))
            # Calculate rectangle points centered on the current point
            rectangle = calculate_rotated_rectangle(current_point, rectangle_length, rectangle_width, angle)
            polygon = arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*coords) for coords in rectangle]), spatial_ref)
            insert_cursor.insertRow([polygon, rectangle_length, rectangle_width, unique_id, type_field, feature, height, county])
            print(f"Processed {i + 1} features...")
    print(f"Polygons created and saved in {output_fc}. Total features processed: {len(points_data)}.")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Probably it is best to post this question in the dedicated GIS stackoverflow section: https://gis.stackexchange.com/ . To include code: put 4 extra spaces before each line and paste it in your message and make sure there is a newline before and after it. Also use the tag "python", this will take care of having pretty highlighting of python keywords,....

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
